# No puedo almacenar los datos de una API en una variable de tipo Array

Tags: javascript, angular, api, variables, requests

resulta que quiero almacenar los datos de una Api en una array, pero los datos no quedan almacenados al imprimir en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado y como pueden ver el array datos se encuentra vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la API compañeros para aportar más información, devuelve un objeto con un array adentro y este array tiene varios objetos:
https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com/

Si alguno tiene una respuesta se lo agradecería mucho, la verdad todavía soy algo principiante en javascript

Comment: Si quedan almacenados, pero despues de un tiempo, por ser una llamada asincrona, para confirmarlo haz un `console.log` dentro del `subscribe`.

Comment: Tienes razón no me había percatado de eso. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor de tu clase, estas llamando a **getDatos** el cual se *limpia* cuando haces correr tu aplicación, en realidad debes llamar a **getDataApi** y dentro del suscribe llamar a **getDatos** y veras que si esta almacenando.

Comment: porque decis se limpia? s

Comment: Quiero decir, cada vez que haces correr tu aplicación tu array datos elimina todos los valores que pueda llegar a tener, y desde la imagen que proporcionaste nunca se le esta llamando a getDataApi

Comment: No soy el que publico la pregunta es correcto llamar desde el subscribe a getDatos pero lo que comentas sobre limpiar y tu respuesta a mi consulta   es errónea

Answer (score 0):

Lo indicado es crear un servicio  y incluir en el a getDataApi() pero  que solo retorne al Observable .
Tener en cuenta que :
El constructor de la clase de componente se ejecuta primero es el punto de partida , antes que
lifecycle hook(metodo ciclo de vida) que se compone de 8 etapas son eventos de enlace de ciclo de vida
ordenadas
algunas de ellas son ngOnChanges: Se activa cuando se cambiamos al valor de una propiedad vinculada:
ngOnInit:Este evento puede usarse  para inicializar la data en el componente es el que te muestro para subscribirnos a la respuesta
otro es  ngAfterViewInit :Se ejecuta cuando la vista del componente se ha inicializado por completo.
El método get retorna un objeto Observable Los observables http han de consumirse mediante el método subscribe
para que realmente se lancen.El flujo de  datos es asíncrono no se sabe en qué momento el observable emitirá un valor por eso nos subscribimos
para lanzarlos y manipular el flujo

```js
//servicio
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService {
    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     
  } 

   getUsers() {
       return return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
   }
}
//componente
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Service } from "path servicio";

@Component({
  selector: "app-users",
  templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./users.component.css"]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
allUsers: User[] = [];
  constructor(public service: Service) { console.log('constructor was called!'),this.getDatos('Desde Constructor')}

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('ngOnInit was called!');
    this.service.getUsers().
subscribe(data:any=>{
this.allUsers=data;getDatos('desde Subscribe!!!!!')};
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
    this.getDatos('Desde AfterViewInit')
  }
  
  
  getDatos(a:string){
    console.log('Datos',this.datos,'desde:',a)
  }
```